# Merge two collections on mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, database

I need to merge two collections into one, but I need to put the document only if it doesn't exists in the first collection. How can I do it? What's the best way?
I saw something about agregation and mapreduce but I am not sure about what to use. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Check out this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696940/merging-two-collections-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no automatic way for that.
Assume u have 2 collection for merge, c1 and c2
You could manually do the merge with

```
db.c1.find().forEach(function(item) {
    db.c2.insert(item);
    db.c1.remove(item);
});
```

u should be careful with that because mongo does not support multi-document-transaction

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest brute-force approach that comes to my mind.

Below, `users` is the collection to which you are going to copy documents from `users2`. I am assuming `_id` is the merge key.

```
use test;

db.users.insert({_id: 1, name: 'Mickey'});
db.users.insert({_id: 2, name: 'Minney'});

db.users2.insert({_id: 1, name: 'Donald'});
db.users2.insert({_id: 2, name: 'Daisy'});
db.users2.insert({_id: 3, name: 'Pluto'});

var users2 = db.users2.find();
while (users2.hasNext()) {
  var u2 = users2.next();
  var u = db.users.findOne({'_id': u2._id});
  if (u == null) {
    db.users.insert(u2);
  }
}
```

`Mickey` and `Minnie` will be preserved and only `Pluto` will be added to `users`.