# how to merge cursors of different collections and order them by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, meteor

is it possible to merge two or more different `collections` and order them by createdAt?

e.g. I have some data like

```
    CollectionA.insert({
        createdAt: new Date(),
        field1: value1,
        field2: value3,
        field3: value2,
    });
    CollectionB.insert({
        createdAt: new Date(),
        field4: value4,
        field5: value5,
        field6: value6,
        field7: value7,
    });
```

I would like to merge and order them on the server that the client get a merged CollectionC later via a subscribe.
How to merge and order the collections? I would like to do this as cheap as possible

Comment: can you please clarify your question. You told that you need to merge `different` collections, but in your example you have only collectionA. Also what would you like to order in these collections?

Comment: Fixed typo and updated question

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Combine data from multiple collections into one..how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696940/merging-two-collections-in-mongodb). Then you can index it by date and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to query both collections together. So you have two solutions:

- pretty bad one: select everything from `collectionA` with one query, select everything from `collectionB` with another, sort everything on application layer and get your results. It is easy to see that once you have any reasonable size, this becomes unscalable. You can do work arounds (like select only elements only close to `createdAt`) but it is still bad.
- what I would do. If the data in collections is that similar, why do you need both collections. Refactor your db and merge them together (if for some reason you need to know which collections they came from add a field `type: 1|2`. This way you will sort on a db layer (not application layer.

How would I merge them. I would do this in mongoshell with:

```
db.collectionA.find().forEach(function(doc){
   db.collectionB.insert(doc);
});
db.collectionA.drop()
```

After this you will end up only with collectionB which will have the documents from both collections.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short: You have to do this on the application side, as cursors are tied to collections. So you have to manually merge the result sets.

After you merged them, you can use the following approach to sort them

```
function sortByField(a,b){
  if(a.fieldName < b.fieldName) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if(a.fieldName == b.fieldName){
     return 0;
  }
  else return 1;
}

var sortedArray = mergedArray.sort(sortByField)
```