# Merge two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, merge, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use MongoDB for several months but with basic usage, and it's maybe the first time that I try to use more complicated functions.

I have two collections :

collection 'trades' :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5878ec66ad251f4fb4d2aacc"), "clubCode" : "43W0K", "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"), "symbol" : "ENGI.PA", "name" : "ENGIE SA", "buyOrSell" : "buy", "orderDone" : true, "quantity" : 12, "price" : 11.99, "fees" : 0.99, "total" : 144.87, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5878f8c339b47f0ee4a3b80b"), "clubCode" : "43W0K", "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"), "symbol" : "PRIO.PA", "name" : "Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR", "buyOrSell" : "buy", "orderDone" : true, "quantity" : 56, "price" : 8.92, "fees" : 0.99, "total" : 500.51, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5878fadf39b47f0ee4a3b80c"), "clubCode" : "43W0K", "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"), "symbol" : "ALVIV.PA", "name" : "Visiativ SA", "buyOrSell" : "buy", "orderDone" : true, "quantity" : 10, "price" : 18.15, "fees" : 0.99, "total" : 182.49, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("587a03319e3fe23138119937"), "clubCode" : "43W0K", "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"), "symbol" : "BIG.PA", "name" : "BigBen Interactive", "buyOrSell" : "buy", "orderDone" : false, "orderType" : "ACL", "quantity" : 83, "price" : 6.01, "fees" : 0.99, "total" : 499.82, "__v" : 0 }
```

collection 'subscriptions' :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922761"), "email" : "aaa@aaa.fr", "clubCode" : "43W0K", "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"), "amount" : 100, "type" : "recurrent", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922762"), "email" : "bbb@bbb.fr", "clubCode" : "43W0K", "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"), "amount" : 100, "type" : "recurrent", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922763"), "email" : "ccc@ccc.fr", "clubCode" : "43W0K", "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"), "amount" : 100, "type" : "recurrent", "__v" : 0 }
```

Each are related to a clubCode (here '43W0K').

I would like to have this result (in another collection or just with an aggregate) :

```
{
    clubCode: "43W0K",
    treasury_moves: [
        {
            date: ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
            wording: "Achat ENGIE SA",
            amount: 144.87
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
            wording: "Achat Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
            amount: 500.51
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
            wording: "Achat Visiativ SA",
            amount: 182.49
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
            wording: "Achat BigBen Interactive",
            amount: 499.82
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"),
            wording: "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            amount: 100
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"),
            wording: "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            amount: 100
        }, {
            date: ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00Z"),
            wording: "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            amount: 100
        }
    ]
}
```

So a merge between 'trades' and 'subscriptions' collections,

- which `date` is equal to `$date` for 'trades' or `$period` for 'subscriptions'
- which `wording` is equal to `Achat $name` for 'trades', or `Subscription $email` for 'subscriptions'
- which `amount` result is equal to `$total` if it's in 'trades', or `$amount` if it's in 'subscriptions'

First of all, is it possible to do this ? With mapreduce ? aggregate ?

I've looking to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696940/merging-two-collections-in-mongodb) which seems similar but I don't succeed to have the result that I want.

If you can help me or just indicate me the way to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible through the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** function in the aggregation framework. You need to run the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.trades.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "subscriptions",
            "localField": "clubCode",
            "foreignField": "clubCode",
            "as": "subs"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$subs" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$clubCode",
            "trades": {
                "$push": {
                    "date": "$date",
                    "wording": { "$concat": ["Achat ", "$name"] },
                    "amount": "$total"
                }
            },
            "subs": {
                "$push": {
                    "date": "$subs.period",
                    "wording": { "$concat": ["Subscription ", "$subs.email"] },
                    "amount": "$subs.amount"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "clubCode": "$_id",
            "_id": 0,
            "treasury_moves": { "$setUnion": ["$subs", "$trades"] }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "clubCode" : "43W0K",
    "treasury_moves" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat ENGIE SA",
            "amount" : 144.87
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat BigBen Interactive",
            "amount" : 499.82
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
            "amount" : 500.51
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Visiativ SA",
            "amount" : 182.49
        }
    ]
}
```

---

In the above pipeline, the first stage involves the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator. This allows you to do a "left outer join" to the other collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. When you run a pipeline against the `trades` collection with
just this step:

```
db.trades.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "subscriptions",
            "localField": "clubCode",
            "foreignField": "clubCode",
            "as": "subs"
        }
    }
])
```

you will get the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5878ec66ad251f4fb4d2aacc"),
    "clubCode" : "43W0K",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
    "symbol" : "ENGI.PA",
    "name" : "ENGIE SA",
    "buyOrSell" : "buy",
    "orderDone" : true,
    "quantity" : 12,
    "price" : 11.99,
    "fees" : 0.99,
    "total" : 144.87,
    "__v" : 0,
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922761"),
            "email" : "aaa@aaa.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922762"),
            "email" : "bbb@bbb.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922763"),
            "email" : "ccc@ccc.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5878f8c339b47f0ee4a3b80b"),
    "clubCode" : "43W0K",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
    "symbol" : "PRIO.PA",
    "name" : "Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
    "buyOrSell" : "buy",
    "orderDone" : true,
    "quantity" : 56,
    "price" : 8.92,
    "fees" : 0.99,
    "total" : 500.51,
    "__v" : 0,
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922761"),
            "email" : "aaa@aaa.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922762"),
            "email" : "bbb@bbb.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922763"),
            "email" : "ccc@ccc.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5878fadf39b47f0ee4a3b80c"),
    "clubCode" : "43W0K",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
    "symbol" : "ALVIV.PA",
    "name" : "Visiativ SA",
    "buyOrSell" : "buy",
    "orderDone" : true,
    "quantity" : 10,
    "price" : 18.15,
    "fees" : 0.99,
    "total" : 182.49,
    "__v" : 0,
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922761"),
            "email" : "aaa@aaa.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922762"),
            "email" : "bbb@bbb.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922763"),
            "email" : "ccc@ccc.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587a03319e3fe23138119937"),
    "clubCode" : "43W0K",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
    "symbol" : "BIG.PA",
    "name" : "BigBen Interactive",
    "buyOrSell" : "buy",
    "orderDone" : false,
    "orderType" : "ACL",
    "quantity" : 83,
    "price" : 6.01,
    "fees" : 0.99,
    "total" : 499.82,
    "__v" : 0,
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922761"),
            "email" : "aaa@aaa.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922762"),
            "email" : "bbb@bbb.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("587c946f3aa3f229a0922763"),
            "email" : "ccc@ccc.fr",
            "clubCode" : "43W0K",
            "period" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "type" : "recurrent",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

For the next step, you will need to flatten the subs array with **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** for processing as your next pipeline stage:

```
db.trades.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "subscriptions",
            "localField": "clubCode",
            "foreignField": "clubCode",
            "as": "subs"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$subs" }
])
```

This will produce `i x j` documents where `i` is the number of documents in the original collection (4) and `j` is the number of array elements (3).

---

The next step, **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**, will then group the 12 documents by the `clubCode` field and create two arrays with subdocuments from the fields specified:

```
db.trades.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "subscriptions",
            "localField": "clubCode",
            "foreignField": "clubCode",
            "as": "subs"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$subs" }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$clubCode",
            "trades": {
                "$push": {
                    "date": "$date",
                    "wording": { "$concat": ["Achat ", "$name"] },
                    "amount": "$total"
                }
            },
            "subs": {
                "$push": {
                    "date": "$subs.period",
                    "wording": { "$concat": ["Subscription ", "$subs.email"] },
                    "amount": "$subs.amount"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output at the pipeline**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "43W0K",
    "trades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat ENGIE SA",
            "amount" : 144.87
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat ENGIE SA",
            "amount" : 144.87
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:03:52.410Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat ENGIE SA",
            "amount" : 144.87
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
            "amount" : 500.51
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
            "amount" : 500.51
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T15:56:32.088Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Lyxor ETF PEA Brazil (Ibovespa) C-EUR",
            "amount" : 500.51
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Visiativ SA",
            "amount" : 182.49
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Visiativ SA",
            "amount" : 182.49
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-13T16:05:35.849Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat Visiativ SA",
            "amount" : 182.49
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat BigBen Interactive",
            "amount" : 499.82
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat BigBen Interactive",
            "amount" : 499.82
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-01-14T10:52:56.208Z"),
            "wording" : "Achat BigBen Interactive",
            "amount" : 499.82
        }
    ],
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription aaa@aaa.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription bbb@bbb.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "wording" : "Subscription ccc@ccc.fr",
            "amount" : 100
        }
    ]
}
```

---

You would need to join the two arrays and ignore duplicates with the **[`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion)** operator in your final aggregation pipeline, **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)**. This will also reshape the documents by replacing the `_id` key from the previous pipeline with the `clubCode` field. Running the final pipeline with those stages will give you the desired result.

Comment: Wow, impressive ! Thanks a lot, it works perfectly fine, and I now understand (well... I believe... :) ) the working of everything !

Thanks again !

Comment: No worries, always happy to help :) if you need further clarification about the pipeline, feel free to ping me in the comments.

Comment: For now, no other questions about what you give to me.

Just another thing, I would like to sort the results by date. I tried to add a 'sort' in the pipeline, but I didn't succeed to sort them.
I tried to put the `{ $sort: { treasury_moves.date:1 } }` after the `$project` one, but it doesn't work.
If i put it after the $unwind, I can sort each collection, but not together.

Do you have any solution for that ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: You could place another `$unwind` after the `$project` step, sort the flattened docs `{ $sort: { treasury_moves.date:1 } }` then regroup with a final `$group` stage. Seems to be the only approach here.

Comment: Yes, perfect ! Thanks again :)